# HP - EnemyAttack Throws error at me :L

Tags: python

This is the code I am using:

```
def EnemyAttack():  
  print("The enemy",enemy, "Attacked!")  
  HP - EnemyAttack  
  if HP < 0 or HP == 0:  
    print("You Were torn to pieces by the",enemy,".")    
  else:   
    print("You managed to withstand the attack by the",enemy, "It growls in  
 frustration.")  
    BattleChoice()
```

... and the error I receive when running:

> Traceback (most recent call last):     File "python", line 83, in
>        File "python", line 62, in EnemyAttack   TypeError:
>   unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'

Comment: I really dont get this -_-

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please format code and error message. Indentation matters. You should also add context and [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As for the error message: What do you expect to happen in the line `HP - EnemyAttack`, when HP is an integer value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at line 3 of your code:

```
HP - EnemyAttack
```

Your `HP` variable is an integer, your `EnemyAttack` is a function not returning a number. If your `EnemyAttack` would return a number, you could use:

```
HP -= EnemyAttack()
```

To decrease `HP` by the number returned by `EnemyAttack`.